# Facebook API like count

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I would like to get the like count of the page that has been shared to the Facebook.

Example:
URL: www.example.com/test-page

I have tried the below way but i did not able to get the like count but possible to get share count.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[url]/access_token=[access_token]

https://graph.facebook.com/[URL]/?fields=fan_count&access_token=[access_token]
```

Comment: the fan count IS the like count. can you be more specific?

Comment: fan_count is for Facebook pages only, not for external URLs. You want the `engagement` field of the `url` node.

Comment: ah, i missed that he tried that one for an external url. good catch.

Comment: Yes you are correct CBroe. Now i can able to access the like count by using field engagement.

Thanks once again.

Comment: To get the Like count of external urls:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12?ids=URL&fields=engagement&access_token=[access_token]